# What is the difference between Vulnerability Assessment and Ethical Hacking?

Tags: vulnerability, professional-education

What is the difference between Vulnerability Assessment and Ethical Hacking?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Information Security! Your second question is off topic in my opinion, so I edited it out. If you disagree, feel free to add it back but I suspect your question would risk being closed.

Answer (score 1):

A vulnerability assessment is a passive analysis of the current security measures in place. This would involve simply looking at systems and seeing if they meet certain criteria.

Ethical Hacking is a form of offensive and active security where deliberate attempts are being made to exploit vulnerabilities in systems to highlight security issues.

Long story short, one is passive, one is active.